# How to read (or restore) files on encrypted SD card after update to Android Oreo?

Tags: updates, encryption, 8.0-oreo

### My situation

I have been using the [encryption of my Android phone’s external SD Card](https://techverse.net/encrypt-android-phones-external-sd-card/) on a Samsung Galaxy J3 (2017) Duos (SM-J330F) ever since I got it. I have recently updated my OS to Android 8.0 (Oreo).

Upon restart a notification was displayed that the encrypted SD card could not be decrypted because it was encrypted on a different device (which is no true; I have been using the same device, but the OS might not be able to recognize this). It is my understanding that [decryption of the SD card is not possible on any other device](https://www.droidviews.com/encrypt-and-decrypt-sd-card-on-samsung-galaxy-devices/).

This might not be the first case where [Android fails to decrypt SD card after update to Oreo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=android+fails+to+decrypt+sd+card+after+update+to+oreo).

### What have I tried?

I have shutdown my device, removed the (micro) SD card, and plugged it in to my notebook. All (?) files are visible, the filenames look okay, but content is not readable. I have then created an image by running

`dd if=/dev/mmcblk0p1 of=~/SANDISKSDHC.img status=progress`

I have reformatted the SD card with my Android device. I have then written back the IMG file to the SD card by running

`dd if=~/SANDISKSDHC.img of=/dev/mmcblk0p1 status=progress`

I have loaded the SD card into my Android device and started it. Again a notification was displayed that the encrypted SD card could not be decrypted because it was encrypted on a different device...

### My resources

- [How do I decrypt files on my SD card that I encrypted using the Settings?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20282/) (doesn't seem to apply to my situation)
- [Encrypted SD card failed after S5 restart](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/182730/) (different situation, but references the next)
- [How to decrypt a microSD card after a factory reset of the device used to encrypt it?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/116750/) (**tried this, did not solve my problem**)
- [Cannot open Airwatch encrypted files on SD card after Android update](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/195233/) (no answer)
- [How to Read marshmallow encrypted memory card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/155626/) (different situation, and I did not understand the procedure linked in the answer)
- [How to restore files on SD Card that was protected by Vault app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/49657/) (different situation)